LL(1) conflict detection equivalence?
LL parser table.
For LL(1), the following rules apply for deciding whether there is a conflict:
for each pair of different productions of the same non-terminal symbol (let's call it A):

strings beginning with the same terminal symbol cannot be output.
two productions cannot simultaneously allow the derivation of an empty (epsilon) string
if an empty string can be output from one production, no string starting with any terminal symbol belonging to FOLLOW(A) can be output from the other production

This is caused by the fact that the terminal symbol is used to select the production; while the first point is clear, points 2 and 3 result from the fact that when outputting the entire string, when the string generated by the productions ends, there is a return to the overriding (in the dynamic sense) production that generates further symbols, you can imagine it as a return to the procedure calling the current procedure. Point 2 follows from the fact that otherwise, for both selection paths, we would have tokens with FOLLOW(A) (in addition to those specific only to those productions)
It follows from conditions 1 and 2 that the FIRST sets should be disjoint for both productions. The third condition is equivalent to the requirement that if an epsilon belongs to the FIRST of one production then the FIRST sets of the other and FOLLOW(A) are disjoint.
I have a question: if there is an epsilon, is it possible to add tokens from FOLLOW(A) to the production set and then only compare sets with each other, is this equivalent, or would such enriched sets cause a conflict with some third set, maybe too weak or too strong would be the check?
